Does HBase read all columns of a row when only a subset of columns is specified?
If my table has just 1 column family with 3 columns: A,B,C. And I read just 1 column, will the entire row be read into memory?
I know that the HFile consists of blocks (64kb each by default). So, if a row is less than 64kb, I understand the HBase will read it into memory, because it's can't read less than the size of a block.
But what about situations when a row spans multiple blocks?
Once again, want to emphasize that I'm talking about reading from a table with just 1 column family.
